# An approach to dissect an input Color; using 8+ static colors and finding their makeup percentage within the input color

Tags: javascript, colors

I need to find an approach for dissecting a given input color, using given static colors (8 or more.. light yellow, violet, white, black, dark brown, teal etc.)

I want to find what percentage the static colors exist in the input color if at all, to gather the makeup.

Example: An RGB or hex color value is input, then passes are made to find out how much of the dark brown, white, teal, etc are used to make up that color exactly.

ex. Color A contains  40% white, 5% black, 35% dark brown, 0% teal, 15% bright yellow etc

I would like to recreate the input color using certain static colors.  I know not all of the static colors can be used, and some would be more effective.

I suppose slider bars for the static colors could be used in order to match the input color visually, but that would not be fast enough, nor accurate.

Over a period of a few weeks, I have searched off and on for certain methods, and found nothing because the search terms give topics far from what i need to know.

note: the static colors would have an RGB/HSL/hex value of their own.

Answer (score 0):

The task is ambiguous. A color is a point in 3D RGB space. So you need a tetrahedra consisting of 4 color to describe a color inside the tetrahedra. The problem is there could be several tetrahedrons matched also there could be no match at all (so you cannot calculate at all). There're no rules described by you which tetrahedra to use in a set of several ones. Plus if you want use several tetrahedrons to describe a color, the task becomes even more ambiguous and complex. Finding distance from the color point to the tetrahedra vertices would give you a hint what amount of each 4 colors exists in the target color.